Why am I getting this error? Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
I am trying to build an interactive map page using Google Maps, as part of a travel diary app for a group project. So far I've just copied and pasted from Google's tutorial, trying to get a map on the page as a starting point.
I cannot for the life of me get rid of this error and it's doing my head in (I get the same error listed 3x if that means anything):
ERROR
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
This is the map page file (tsx):
import React from 'react';
import {APIProvider, Map, MapCameraChangedEvent} from '@vis.gl/react-google-maps';

const MapPage = () => (
 <APIProvider apiKey={'My API key here'} onLoad={() => console.log('Maps API has loaded.')}>
   <Map
      defaultZoom={13}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: -33.860664, lng: 151.208138 }}
      onCameraChanged={(ev: MapCameraChangedEvent) =>
        console.log('camera changed:', ev.detail.center, 'zoom:', ev.detail.zoom)
      }>
   </Map>
 </APIProvider>
);

export default MapPage;

I don't get an error when going to the homepage of the app, only when I go to the route for the map page.
Troubleshooting so far:
I've read pretty much every post on here from someone with the same issue.
When I previously had the same error, it was to do with how React components were being imported/exported throughout the app. I've gone through and checked these all again.
I created a brand new project and just tried out the map code again. It works perfectly fine here. This app was created with Vite though, and our group project was created with create-react-app. Could this be an issue? It's too late to change this really.
Since it worked fine in a Vite app, I thought it must either be caused by some other part of code that isn't present in the new test app, or to do with how the build tools/dependencies/modules worked in each.
Found a suggestion to add "type": "module" into the package.json but this brought up an error as we were using "require" somewhere. Once I fixed this, it reverted back to the same error as above.
I've tried restarting my computer, restarting Visual Studio Code, deleting node modules and reinstalling, deduping, checking I'm on the latest version of everything. Every single bit of troubleshooting that ChatGPT has suggested and I'm losing my mind.
I'm a beginner and only have experience with extremely simple React apps so I'm at a loss here and could do with some help please. TIA!
Edited to add:
I tried abandoning Google Maps API and using Leaflet, I get the same error:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:198140:25)
    at MapContainerComponent (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:231707:66)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:124680:22)
    at updateForwardRef (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:127929:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:129990:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:114936:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:114980:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:115037:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134935:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:134183:16)


If it helps, it says the error is occurring:
at useMapInstances
at APIProvider
at renderWithHooks
at mountIndeterminateComponent
at beginWork
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev
at invokeGuardedCallback
at beginWork$1

can you please any working code in sandbox? It looks like you are trying to set a state variable somewhere but it is not able to set it correctly and hence giving you that error.

I've tried to put all the code in sandbox but getting another error.
Then I tried just the part of the code I'm actually working on but idk if that's helpful!
Thanks if you can take a look :)

The error clearly says it's coming from MapContainerComponent, so: show that code in your post.

Did you remove your API key from the question? Because apiKey={'My API key here'} is not really a valid API key. If that's not the case, the error stems from the MapContainerComponent, whatever that is. I can't find it in the sandbox nor the library's sourcecode.
